# Category Conditional tags on opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using opencart v.1.5.1 and on the 
/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl

how do I write a condition like this:

```
If main current display is of a parent category:
show this image

else (if it's a subcategory display ):
show different image
```

because this is what i want to achieve:

on this site (parent category): http://www.guitarplayback.com/Jam-Tracks
it's a banner image

on the subcategory : http://www.guitarplayback.com/Jam-Tracks/Ballad-Jam-Tracks
it's an image with description on the right side

Comment: could you explain a little bit more ? what is it exactly you want to do ?

Comment: YOu have a style problem when you change the lagnuage some thing goes wrong please go to your main page and check for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not test this yet but this should work for you.
Try this on controller/product/category.php **before** *$this->data['products'] = array();*

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
  if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id && $category['top']) {
     $this->data['topCatImage'] = '1';
  }
}
```

On category.tpl

```
if (isset($topCatImage)) {
   show this image
} else {
   show other image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

working on something similar. Hope it helps others, Got break some more code:

**catalog\controller\product**

```
$cat_array = explode ("_", $path);
$top_cat_id = $cat_array[0];            
$cat_Image = $this->model_catalog_category->getCatImage($top_cat_id);
if ($cat_Image) {
    //show this image
    $this->data['image'] = $cat_Image['image'];
}
```

**catalog\model\catalog**

```
 public function getCatImage($category_id) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT image FROM " . DB_PREFIX . 
    "category AS cat LEFT JOIN category AS cats ON cats.parent_id = cat.category_id WHERE cat.parent_id =0 AND cat.category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "'");

    return $query->row;

}
```

**catalog\view\theme\default\template\product**

```
 <?php if ($image) { ?>
       <div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></div>
 <?php } else { ?>
       <div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $OTHERimage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></div> 
 <?php } ?>
```